# Node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)

Tags: node.js, laravel, ubuntu, npm

I'm facing a problem when I type this command " **npm run production** " or "**npm run watch**", this message apprears : **node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node).**

1. **Ubuntu version** : 18.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0 x86_64)
2. **Nodejs version** : v16.17.0
3. **nvm version** : 0.39.1

**my package.json** :

```json
{
    "name":"Wanted.com",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "homepage":"https://w-ted.com/index",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies":{
        "npm-watch" : "^0.6.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
        "alpinejs": "^3.4.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.1.0",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.11.3",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
        "postcss": "^8.2.1",
        "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
        "pusher-js": "^7.0.3",
        "sass-loader": "^12.4.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.0.2",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.7",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
    },
    "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^2.6.14"
    }
}
```

[Package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajlfT.png)

Regards,

Comment: Please post the code as text, an image.

Comment: What environment are you deploying this to? Looks like you are building modules locally in a different environment than your deployment environment.

Comment: i'm deploying this on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0 x86_64)

Answer (score -2):

i used this way : https://help.heroku.com/R7DTSTD0/fix-node-js-error-version-glibc_2-28-not-found

so i downgrade the node version. yap it is not -what i want-solution, but at least it solve me,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).